# Add a variable to each dataframe in a list equal to the dataframe names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes with years as names (i.e., 2020, 2021, 2022, etc.). I want to add a year variable to each dataframe equal to its name. I was able to add the year variable = NA but could not figure out how to reference the dataframe name. Code I have so far is below:

```
data_list <- lapply(data_list, function(x) cbind(x, Year = NA))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, we can use `Map` to loop over the `list` and the corresponding column names of the `list` and `cbind` to create new column

```
data_list <- Map(cbind, data_list, Year = names(data_list))
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
data_list <- imap(data_list, ~ .x %>%
                          mutate(Year = .y))
```